# How to downgrade xcode completely from the terminal/shell?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm not too familiar with mac and iOS but I need to downgrade xcode on a mac host for CI stuff (current app build is failing on xcode 12). I have access to the host via jumphost and I'm not sure if I can connect via VNC (I also don't like this since it's terribly slow) and most of the guides need a UI to download xcode. Any ideas on how to do this completely via terminal?

Answer (score 10):

First, download an older version of Xcode (you will need to be signed in to open the [Downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/)).  Here is the [Xcode releases page](https://xcodereleases.com) with downloads and release notes.

Install the desired version.

After install, switch to the desired version (for example 11.2 below) via terminal using a command like this:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcodex.11.2.app
```

Comment: After downloading you still need to install it first. The downloaded format is XIP

Comment: You don't have to download it directly to the target machine, though. You could download it to a local machine and then copy the downloaded .xip package over to the target machine.