# Upgrade from xCode 14.2 to 14.3 PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode14

I've upgraded from xcode 14.2 to xcode 14.3 beta, and now I can't archive anymore for Any iOS Device (arm64) with the following error :

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks

mkdir -p /Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Max-dmwafkgdrzqavzcmbdjbjgmmuxby/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Release_preprod/BuildProductsPath/Release_preprod-iphoneos/MaxApp.app/Frameworks

Symlinked...

rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/ActionSheetPicker_3_0.framework" "/Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Max-dmwafkgdrzqavzcmbdjbjgmmuxby/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Release_preprod/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MaxApp.app/Frameworks"

building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/max/Workspace/MaxApp/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/ActionSheetPicker_3_0.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)

done



sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec

total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Any idea why it works fine with xCode 14.2 and not with xCode 14.3 beta please ?

I tryed to delete the [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks script, but it has re-created it and get the same issue.
I tryed to build and debug in a simulator, and it works fine.
I tryed to delete "EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]" = arm64; in the .pbxproj file

Comment: Tested again with xCode 14.3 beta 2, and still have the same issue :(
Any idea please ?

Comment: We used `use_frameworks!` and it led to the same errors. adding 
`, :modular_headers => false;` after pods that don't work in static mode helped.

Comment: Having the same issue, found because Xcode Cloud failed to build. So far I haven't found a solution — only this in the Xcode release notes `Xcode 14.3 includes a new module verifier that generates diagnostics for issues in a framework’s modules.`, which might be relevant... or maybe not.

Comment: There is an active issue on the Cocoapods repo for this. See it https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808, and an open PR with potential fix https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/11828

Comment: Check this to fix this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75947102/6667442

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update 2**: On the 18th of April 2023 the new CocoaPods version 1.12.1 got finally released  and it includes the fixes needed to solve the problem that this ticket is about: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.12.1

Note: if you edited files in your project to solve the problem, or switched to the master branch of CocoaPods, then you might want to undo those changes as they are not needed anymore due to the release of CocoaPods 1.12.1, if you keep the changes you might run into problems in the future, see my "EDIT" at the end of this ticket for more

**Update 1**: the pull request with a fix (mentioned in my initial answer) has  been merged into the master branch of cocoapods (on april 3rd: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808#issuecomment-1494709564) but it is not yet in a release, it should be part of the next release 1.12.1 (as one of the maintainers commented here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/11828#issuecomment-1496357883) but as of now this has not happend yet (you can keep an eye on the releases list here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases)

if you use ruby gem to install your cocoapods and don't want to do the downgrade from Xcode 14.3 to 14.2 (as described in my initial answer) then you can switch manually to the master branch of cocoa pods using the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods.git --branch master
cd CocoaPods
gem build cocoapods.gemspec
gem install ./cocoapods-*.gem
```

and finally you need to manually remove the previously installed pods as well as the pods lock file from your project, then re-build the pods folder using the command specific to your framework (for example for capacitor use: `npx cap sync`) or use this command:

```
pod install
```

**Initial answer**: I have a similar issue, it seems to be related to cocoa pods, there is a ticket about the problem here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808#issuecomment-1481244508

a pull request with a potential fix has already been submited by a github user: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/11828

if you want to apply the fix yourself and not wait for a release, you can do what the author of the fix suggested (in his follow up comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808#issuecomment-1480802886):

> Workaround is to update all the generated ...-frameworks.sh files to add the -f flag to the call to readlink. In other words, replace:

```
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
```

> with

```
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

if you scroll down one comment you will find a comment by another github user with a another temporary solution which is to downgrade to xcode build tools from 14.3 to 14.2 for builds (works for both builds in the IDE and builds in the xcode cloud):

here are the screenshots from that ticket, showing how to downgrade from  14.3 command line tools version to a 14.2 version in the Xcode IDE:

> in your Xcode IDE (Xcode 14.3) go to "Settings" open the "Locations" tab and then select "Command Line Tools" and choose "Xcode 14.2 (14C18)"

[image: Xcode IDE change command line tools version being used]

and if you are using the Xcode cloud to do your builds, refer to this screenshot instead to change the Xcode version in your workflow (you can edit the workflow either in your Xcode IDE or on the appstore connect website (https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/)):

> edit your "workflow" > "Environment" and then select as Xcode Version "Xcode 14.2 (14C18)" (instead of 14.3)

[image: xcode cloud downgrade xcode version]

**EDIT**: I recommend watching for a 1.12.1 release here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases which will have the fix, you can also subscribe to the github ticket and PR (mentioned above), so that when the fix is released you don't manually downgrade the xcode version anymore (it is always best to use the latest version, if you keep it downgraded it will cause trouble in the future as at some point packages and tools you use for your app will not be compatible with xcode 14.2) or if you chose to use the cocoapods master branch, you might after the release want  to undo that change so that you are sure to use the release version again and not the master branch (the master branch might include features that are still unstable because they are in beta compared to the release version which is deemed to be stable)

Comment: And if you no longer have 14.2 locally, try this way to dowload 14.2 and manually switch/downgrade: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64422114/117750

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: If you can add more than just links, feel free to flag for undeletion

Answer (score 85):

### **Updated for those who are facing this in Xcode 15:**

Resolving this problem was one of the most tricky errors in my life..

I resolved this for a Flutter project, in your case it might be a native iOS project.

### **It's easier to do the following:**

1- Open your project using XCode

2- Search of `"Symlinked..."`

3- Replace `source="$(readlink "${source}")"` with `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`

4- Try again to build your project or export your ipa it should work

[image]

**For reference check more details [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808)**

Comment: do we need to do anything in terms of the cocoa pods update/ install or other changes?

Comment: It depends on your CocoaPods version, better to be up to date @VikramSinha

Comment: This worked for my Flutter app too. Thanks a lot, probably saved me many hours of troubleshooting! By the way, this was the error I was seeing before applying this fix: `DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled) ** ARCHIVE FAILED **`

Comment: If I hadn't seen this answer, I would have been crazy downgrading Xcode right about now. Thank you.

Comment: Nice answer, it's worked for me in direct native iOS app. I have update my Xcode in to 14.3 then I got this issue and it's resolved.

Comment: Extra credits for giving specific instruction how to quickly to find the file!

Comment: Good job bro ...

Comment: Not working in my case. Archive getting failed

Comment: Thank you!!! Still had to do this with XCode 15...

Comment: As I searched for Symlinked, there was already ' source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"' in my project Pods-ProjectName-frameworks file, so still encountering the same issue, not working for me as well...Am I missing something or the issue is into other problems idk :-(

Answer (score 2):

If you used Xcode or Xcode Cloud, just downgrade to 14.2.

For Xcode:

[image: change Command line tool]

For Xcode Cloud:

[image: change the environment]

Comment: Thank you! I was unable to release my app update since XCode Cloud was failing. This buys me some time until CocoaPods gets things worked out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering an error while exporting a build in Xcode 14.3, there's good news - Cocoapods will be releasing a build (version 1.12.1) soon that addresses the issue.

In the meantime, you can try the following solution: navigate to the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/` directory and open the `Pods-ProjectName-frameworks.sh` file. Then, replace line 44 with code `"$(readlink "${source}")"` with `"$(readlink -f "${source}")"`.

Source: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/11828

The cocoapods version of `1.12.1` is yet to release.

Hope it will work.