# Xcode 14: Rsync "failed: No such file or directory (2)" Error on Archive

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am trying to archive my project in Xcode 14.3 and I am receiving a build error during the "Embed Pods Framework" Phase.

```
rsync: [sender] change_dir "/Users/benjaminhill/src/stagey_producer/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

I have tried deleting my podfile.lock, cleaning my build folder, upgrading rsync, restarting xcode. Runs fine in Xcode 13 and the project builds fine in Xcode 14 - just running into problems when Archiving.

Here's the full log:

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/benjaminhill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/stagey_producer-dzqglqxhgmgoreferuvikcueqhdz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/stagey_producer/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/stagey_producer.build/Release-iphoneos/stagey_producer.build/Script-89C3F347056509769E64FEDC.sh (in target 'stagey_producer' from project 'stagey_producer')
    cd /Users/benjaminhill/src/stagey_producer
    /bin/sh -c /Users/benjaminhill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/stagey_producer-dzqglqxhgmgoreferuvikcueqhdz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/stagey_producer/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/stagey_producer.build/Release-iphoneos/stagey_producer.build/Script-89C3F347056509769E64FEDC.sh

mkdir -p /Users/benjaminhill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/stagey_producer-dzqglqxhgmgoreferuvikcueqhdz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/stagey_producer/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/stagey_producer.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework" "/Users/benjaminhill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/stagey_producer-dzqglqxhgmgoreferuvikcueqhdz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/stagey_producer/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/stagey_producer.app/Frameworks"
sending incremental file list
rsync: [sender] change_dir "/Users/benjaminhill/src/stagey_producer/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 19 bytes  received 12 bytes  62.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1356) [sender=3.2.7]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: Appears to be related to: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade from xCode 14.2 to 14.3 PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486713/upgrade-from-xcode-14-2-to-14-3-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit)

Answer (score 49):

Install the latest version of `cocoapods` >= `1.12.1`

This version has been released with these fixes. Try the following commands to install the latest version.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod install
```

If you want to use `cococapods` version < `1.12.1`.
You can try the following steps:

1. Navigate to the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/` directory
2. Open the `Pods-ProjectName-frameworks.sh` file.
3. Replace line 44 with code `"$(readlink "${source}")"` with `"$(readlink -f "${source}")"`.

Source: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/11828

Hope it will work.

Comment: But what if I am using git to archive a project build and it archiving on the server then how can I fix this issue?

Comment: This saves my day

Comment: Worked for me too when using it together with fastlane but had to completely remove`cococapods` and `fastlane` gem before and install them again.

Answer (score 31):

1. Search the file in the bottom-left corner of Xcode

   ```
   Pods-[your project name]-frameworks
   ```
2. Search for `source="$(readlink "${source}")"` and replace it with:

   ```
   #    source="$(readlink "${source}")"
   source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
   ```

Answer (score 4):

There are two steps to solving this
**Step 1:**
Navigate to the Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/ directory and open the Pods-ProjectName-frameworks.sh file. Then, replace the string "$(readlink "${source}")" with "$(readlink -f "${source}")"

**Step 2:**
Upgrade all pods libraries with minimum deployments of 8.0 to 11.0

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123852

if [ -L "${source}" ]; then
echo "Symlinked..."
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
echo "Linked: ${source}"
fi

Comment: Is this an answer?

Answer (score -1):

just update the cocoapod and restart your system after every os Update it is normal to have this kind of error while making archive. I tried update cocoapod and it worked for me

- open up your terminal and type in the command “sudo gem update cocoapods”
- Restart system
- reinstall pods

that's it it will work for you.