# Build failed after upgrading Xcode 14.3

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode14

After upgrading Xcode 14.3 my flutter run failed to run on iOS specifically but I am able to run on Android.

I am getting following error:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2023-04-03 17:29:33.364 xcodebuild[97688:923371] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
    xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
            { id:6EB5FA1B-46DC-4E2D-BA30-9BF413BCB06F }

        Available destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
            { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00006000-001429C12E23801E }
            { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }

Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/k9/wbd7hvx90_s_1_rt6sqg61b80000gn/T/flutter_tools.3s0yqP/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirw6n3UV/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

Comment: you can checkout this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486713/upgrade-from-xcode-14-2-to-14-3-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit)

Answer (score 5):

Change the

```
<LaunchAction

      buildConfiguration = "Release" to  buildConfiguration = "Debug"
```

in Runner.xcscheme.

Comment: Using the navigation of `XCODE: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme` ... then Build Configuration from `Release` to `Debug`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when building an xcf framework. The reason was in my case the DTVCoreDeviceEnableState (whatever that is).

> xcodebuild[97688:923371] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)

My solution was to add the -userdefault parameter to the xcodebuild command line:

```
xcodebuild  -project myproject.xcodeproj\
        -scheme myScheme\
        -destination 'generic/platform=iOS,name=Any iOS Device'\
        -configuration Release\
        -sdk iphoneos\
        -action build\
        -derivedDataPath ./DerivedData\
        -userdefault=DVTEnableCoreDevice=enabled
```

Make sure, that the -userdefault parameter is the last parameter in the command line. Otherwise, the parameter was ignored (at least in my case).

Answer (score -1):

First, open project in xcode,

and using the navigation of XCODE go to

Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

... then

Build Configuration from Release to Debug