# XCode 14.3 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, error-handling, xcode14.3

I am getting Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code after updating to XCode 14.3.
Earlier it was working fine. Tried multiple solutions still result is same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade from xCode 14.2 to 14.3 PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486713/upgrade-from-xcode-14-2-to-14-3-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround is to update all the generated ...-frameworks.sh files to add the -f flag to the call to readlink. In other words, need to replace:

source="$(readlink "${source}")"

with

source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"

Seems this is CocoaPods issue...

Comment: There are many duplicates explaining this already. This whole question and answer should be deleted as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after the update. Updating Cocoapods and the CryptoSwift helped in my case. Try to update everything as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure how I got this to work in the end but it was a combination of these things:

- Downgrading to Xcode 14.2
- Upgrading to Cocoapods 1.12.1
- Updating Flutter to 3.10.5
- Removing Flutter Version Management (FVM)
- Updating all dependencies

Honestly, I think FVM was the final problem, I'm really not sure though. Just glad that after 3-4 hours of solid trial and error my project now builds again.