# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code (xcode 14.3 -> flutter)

Tags: flutter, xcode

PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/irem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-azvlvtersluyrwbaiiqihxzjftyu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-92B786FDFB4596576A3C7EDC.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
cd /Users/irem/git-flutter/sbs_hbys_flutter/ios
/bin/sh -c /Users/irem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-azvlvtersluyrwbaiiqihxzjftyu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-92B786FDFB4596576A3C7EDC.sh

mkdir -p /Users/irem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-azvlvtersluyrwbaiiqihxzjftyu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.framework" "/Users/irem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-azvlvtersluyrwbaiiqihxzjftyu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/irem/git-flutter/sbs_hbys_flutter/ios/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/c2cb9645-dafc-11ed-aa26-6ec1e3b3f7b3/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I started getting this error after updating to xcode version 14.3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade from xCode 14.2 to 14.3 PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486713/upgrade-from-xcode-14-2-to-14-3-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved with a workaround to update all the generated `...-frameworks.sh` files to add the `-f` flag to the call to `readlink`. In other words, need to replace:

```
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
```

With:

```
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

Seems this is CocoaPods issue...

Comment: And this is covered by the other question I linked, along with many others.

Comment: This is the original author of the solution I thin but thank you for sharing 

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808#issuecomment-1480802886