# Cocoapods 1.11 with Xcode 15.0.1 "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" when trying to Archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have a project with cocoapods, version 1.11.3 in Xcode 15.0.1

and I'm getting this error when I try to Archive:

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

it only happens when I try to Archive! building & running works.
it started happening after I merged branches...
I suspect it has to do with cocoapods since it also happens on an untouched branch.

I tried to delete the pods & reinstall them:

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

here is the detailed error:

> PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-burmjscxlkyhsbbtmpwfsqnfuxxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myProject/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/myProject.build/Release-iphoneos/myProject.build/Script-F6E2B1F551D02A420E6B6832.sh (in target 'myProject' from project 'myProject')
> cd /Users/myUser/Documents/Programming/MyProject
> /bin/sh -c /Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-burmjscxlkyhsbbtmpwfsqnfuxxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myProject/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/myProject.build/Release-iphoneos/myProject.build/Script-F6E2B1F551D02A420E6B6832.sh
>
> mkdir -p
> /Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-burmjscxlkyhsbbtmpwfsqnfuxxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myProject/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/myProject.app/Frameworks
> Symlinked... rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter
> "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/"
> --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AWSCognito.framework"
> "/Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-burmjscxlkyhsbbtmpwfsqnfuxxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myProject/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/myProject.app/Frameworks"
> building file list ... rsync: link_stat
> "/Users/myUser/Documents/Programming/MyProject/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AWSCognito.framework"
> failed: No such file or directory (2) done
>
> sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec total size is 0
> speedup is 0.00 rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code
> 23) at
> /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/d9889869-120b-11ee-b796-7a03568b17ac/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996)
> [sender=2.6.9] Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit
> code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade from xCode 14.2 to 14.3 PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486713/upgrade-from-xcode-14-2-to-14-3-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit)

Comment: I'm already on Xcode 15.0.1 :P

Answer (score 1):

the problems seems to be a bug in cocoapods version.

I updated the version using:

```
> gem install cocoapods
```

and reinstalled my pods:

```
> pod deintegrate
> pod install
```

Comment: Well, that version was 2 years old. Maybe it was some compatability issue